# Callbacks for Adapter interface in Android

Tags: android

I was looking at the Adapter interface documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html. I found that there are several callback methods that these interface has like

**abstract Object    getItem(int position)**
Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.

**abstract long  getItemId(int position)**
Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list.

**abstract int   getItemViewType(int position)**
Get the type of View that will be created by getView(int, View, ViewGroup) for the specified item.

**abstract int   getViewTypeCount()**
Returns the number of types of Views that will be created by getView(int, View, ViewGroup).

which are usually not implemented. I haven't found their implementation an any of the
Adapter interface implementations that I have come across.  The documentation fails to explain when they will be called and how they can be put to good use. No examples whatsoever. Would appreciate if someone can shed some light on them.

Comment: `ArrayAdapter.getItem()` must sure be implemented, if I'm not veeeery mistaken. Besides, you couldn't use a single `Adapter` implementation in an app if these weren't implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those methods will be called by the AdapterView (for exeample, a ListView) that is linked to your Adapter.

During the AdapterView drawing phase, those methods will be called in order for the view to get the right data to display at a specific place on the screen.

You should google for Adapter tutorial (ex : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: I definitely see a couple of these on the link you have specified. Thanks Vincent. I am actually looking for some detailed information about when a particular call back is called in the lifecycle and what part they play.

Comment: Since you are closest to what I was looking for I would mark that as an answer